# Portfolio Optimisation under participation constraints

Tags: r, optimization, constraints, finance, portfolio

I am trying to find a set of hedge ratios by optimising a portfolio for minimum variance under participation constraints of the assets. Ultimately I would like  to optimise the assets weights for other measures of risk such as minimum CVaR, VaR or maximum return/risk.

My portfolio comprises 9 series. 1 domestic asset and 4 international assets which are 0% currency hedged:

```
"D_Asset1","F_Asset2","F_Asset3","F_Asset4","F_Asset5"
```

I have also series for those that are 100% currency hedged:

```
"H_F_Asset2","H_F_Asset3","H_F_Asset4","H_F_Asset5"
```

The sum of the portfolio asset weights should be equal to one and long only (i.e no leverage / shorting), the domestic asset will have a weight of 60 %. The other asset will have group constraints so that the sum of the hedged and unhedged asset equal a fix target weight (i.e the weight in my benchmark). The group constraints are defined as:

```
("F_Asset2"+"H_F_Asset2") = 0.2  & ("F_Asset2"+"H_F_Asset2") >= 0
("F_Asset3"+"H_F_Asset3") = 0.1  & ("F_Asset3"+"H_F_Asset3") >= 0
("F_Asset4"+"H_F_Asset4") = 0.05  & ("F_Asset4"+"H_F_Asset4") >= 0
("F_Asset5"+"H_F_Asset5") = 0.05  & ("F_Asset5"+"H_F_Asset5") >= 0
```

Therefore I should be able to derive through the weights optimisation the hedge ratio for each of my assets by looking at the proportionality of the optimised weights in each unhedged/hedged groups.  I have tried to code this as follows:

```
opt_data <- as.timeSeries(Asset_returns[,c"D_Asset1","F_Asset2","F_Asset3","F_Asset4","F_Asset5","H_F_Asset2","H_F_Asset3","H_F_Asset4","H_F_Asset5")])

spec <- portfolioSpec()
setSolver(spec) <- "solveRquadprog"

cons <- c("eqsumW['D_Asset1']=0.6","eqsumW[c('F_Asset2','H_F_Asset2')]=0.2","eqsumW[c('F_Asset3','H_F_Asset3')]=0.1","eqsumW[c('F_Asset4','H_F_Asset4')]=0.05","eqsumW[c('F_Asset5','H_F_Asset5')]=0.05")


portfolioConstraints(list(mu=apply(opt_data,2,function(x) mean(x)),sigma=cov(opt_data)), spec,cons)

minriskPortfolio(list(mu=apply(opt_data,2,function(x) mean(x)),sigma=cov(opt_data),spec,constraints = cons)
```

This does not seem to work as the sum of my assets end up being allocated to the hedged asset 4  (0.3809) an 5 (0.6191) only an the fixed weight for the other group of assets is not respected...so I am obviously doing something wrong. Below is the print i get when running my script forr the below data sample.

```
Title:
MV Minimum Risk Portfolio 
Estimator:         covEstimator 
Solver:            solveRquadprog 
Optimize:          minRisk 
Constraints:       LongOnly 

Portfolio Weights:
D_Asset1   F_Asset2   F_Asset3   F_Asset4   F_Asset5 H_F_Asset2 H_F_Asset3 
 0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000    
H_F_Asset4 H_F_Asset5 
  0.3809     0.6191 

Covariance Risk Budgets:
D_Asset1   F_Asset2   F_Asset3   F_Asset4   F_Asset5 H_F_Asset2 H_F_Asset3 
    0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000  0.0000    
H_F_Asset4 H_F_Asset5 
0.3809     0.6191 

Target Return and Risk:
[1] -0.0052

Description:
 Thu Oct 27 13:53:36 2016 by user: 43951663
```

My series are as follows:

```
    GMT
                D_Asset1     F_Asset2     F_Asset3      F_Asset4      F_Asset5    H_F_Asset2    H_F_Asset3   H_F_Asset4   H_F_Asset5
2002-07-05  0.0060728958 -0.013756357 -0.011423593  0.0134417810 -0.0003016946 -0.0009105038 -0.0018985396  0.014808963 -0.003882658
2002-07-12 -0.0897779000 -0.085188382 -0.089815019 -0.0138095353 -0.0762572363 -0.0685047064 -0.0832575916 -0.022109799 -0.047944944
2002-07-19 -0.0943660524 -0.046920616 -0.030421831 -0.0382901308 -0.0624865993 -0.0794080445 -0.0524289818 -0.031577514 -0.041396426
2002-07-26  0.0133063390 -0.057651106 -0.020437497 -0.0728233620 -0.0456981099  0.0064529146 -0.0396719802 -0.054443226 -0.024872592
2002-08-02  0.0112493491  0.009167815  0.016499805  0.0103302726  0.0252948946  0.0143938534  0.0118099642  0.014237543  0.026552984
2002-08-09  0.0802254120  0.067077593  0.057022734  0.0469759343  0.0558895137  0.0513020851  0.0548215098  0.029355000  0.019311812
2002-08-16  0.0121210802  0.004739185  0.002730157 -0.0071254354 -0.0147625074  0.0220800644 -0.0005414763 -0.017939892 -0.013482516
2002-08-23  0.0254279436  0.028461524  0.013045475  0.0007546919  0.0223311149  0.0133616906  0.0279480422  0.005884930  0.008278473
2002-08-30 -0.0478436889 -0.049203575 -0.039813657 -0.0356601715 -0.0256056009 -0.0276201640 -0.0386866322 -0.025089402 -0.004296057
2002-09-06 -0.0320257540 -0.038044390 -0.028008660 -0.0577045132 -0.0281928317 -0.0252990267 -0.0312053440 -0.049959243 -0.021289249
2002-09-13 -0.0005754118 -0.031013743 -0.024805745 -0.0045048220 -0.0035485481 -0.0055489175 -0.0259398560  0.017170857  0.004670684
2002-09-20 -0.0544596063 -0.049806038 -0.037835532  0.0040695629 -0.0467206777 -0.0523013152 -0.0589901499  0.020442551 -0.049443302
2002-09-27 -0.0264640157  0.003081610  0.011115685  0.0119000112 -0.0229705875 -0.0220045767  0.0091850943  0.009544600 -0.014769134
2002-10-04 -0.0350683237 -0.044400596 -0.026363396 -0.0591064104 -0.0404089273 -0.0317751096 -0.0394601664 -0.049204737 -0.028352867
2002-10-11  0.0455968470  0.047623114  0.034835901 -0.0516194024  0.0202454036  0.0435196284  0.0364044803 -0.047211423  0.013827130
2002-10-18  0.0682138514  0.050215807  0.044584318  0.0531850741  0.0789798029  0.0584691831  0.0566157920  0.055481410  0.060939407
2002-10-25  0.0112759198 -0.016565486 -0.019723747 -0.0234843100  0.0107604217  0.0149227748 -0.0177273307 -0.028938189  0.010213889
2002-11-01 -0.0040060015  0.012830724 -0.013284706  0.0043773949 -0.0193135586  0.0053397013  0.0007975884 -0.003459391 -0.015845981
2002-11-08 -0.0235192733 -0.004405182  0.008119140 -0.0033849145 -0.0101840271 -0.0059125661 -0.0036278513 -0.004716045  0.011824785
2002-11-15  0.0227169708  0.027997661  0.013501476 -0.0219131086  0.0096590849  0.0160309555  0.0242988333 -0.022932122  0.014512210
2002-11-22  0.0237869242  0.018522337  0.020965808  0.0062667869  0.0233331986  0.0242851881  0.0316120790  0.026096681  0.019139845
```

I would be quite happy to use another optimiser as long it is in R and allows me to handle other measure of risk such as CVaR, VaR etc...Any idea on how to solve for this problem would be really helpful to me and probably others on this forum.

Answer (score 0):

There are typos in your code. Review the following lines?

```
opt_data <- as.timeSeries(Asset_returns[,c("D_Asset1","F_Asset2","F_Asset3","F_Asset4","F_Asset5","H_F_Asset2","H_F_Asset3","H_F_Asset4","H_F_Asset5")])
```

Whit upper cons:

```
cons <- c("eqsumW['D_Asset1']=0.6","maxsumW[c('F_Asset2','H_F_Asset2')]=0.2","maxsumW[c('F_Asset3','H_F_Asset3')]=0.1","maxsumW[c('F_Asset4','H_F_Asset4')]=0.05","maxsumW[c('F_Asset5','H_F_Asset5')]=0.05")
```

I got:

```
minriskPortfolio(list(mu=apply(opt_data,2,function(x) mean(x)),sigma=cov(opt_data)),spec,constraints = cons)

Title:
 MV Minimum Risk Portfolio 
 Estimator:         covEstimator 
 Solver:            solveRquadprog 
 Optimize:          minRisk 
 Constraints:       

Portfolio Weights:
  D_Asset1   F_Asset2   F_Asset3   F_Asset4   F_Asset5 H_F_Asset2 H_F_Asset3 
    0.6000     0.0308     0.1000     0.0000     0.0000     0.1692     0.0000 
H_F_Asset4 H_F_Asset5 
    0.0500     0.0500 

Covariance Risk Budgets:
  D_Asset1   F_Asset2   F_Asset3   F_Asset4   F_Asset5 H_F_Asset2 H_F_Asset3 
    0.6932     0.0283     0.0762     0.0000     0.0000     0.1557     0.0000 
H_F_Asset4 H_F_Asset5 
    0.0172     0.0294 

Target Return and Risk:
[1] -0.0043
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Robert, this is really useful. May I ask why you use maxsumW in the box constraints ? I thought that if you used EqsumW this would impose that asset group would have to sum up to the desired weight whilst leaving  either of the asset in the group to vary between zero and the target weight.   I understood that if you used minsumW or maxsumW  this would insure that the assets in the  group  would have a minimum  or maximum imposed weight nbut that the group could vary above / below this weight? however the above seem to do what I am after so I am very thankful.

Comment: I used `maxsumW` just to have more possibilities, but if necessary you could continue using `eqsumW`

Comment: Thank you Robert, I think eqsumW is more appropriate for what I am trying to solve. Thank you for your help much appreciated